# one section overlapped by other on html page

Tags: css, html, layout

I created a page with some layout with css:). Problem is that Section area is overlaping Header area:)... how to solve this? The header area should be at the top, and after there should be section area displayed

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy86p6os/)

HTML code:

```
<header style="width: auto; outline: 1px solid red;position: relative; ">
    <div style="width: 150px; outline: 1px solid green;">XXXXX picture XXXXX picture XXXXX picture</div>
    <div style="width: 810px; height: 70px; outline: 1px solid yellow">
      <div style='position: relative; width: auto; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid red;'>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:50%; height:20px; width: 100%; margin-top:-10px; outline:   1px solid green; ">
         <div style="float: left; padding: 0 20;" class="blue">News</div>
         <div style="float: left; padding: 0 20;" class="blue">Tax Tips</div>
         <div style="float: left; padding: 0 20;" class="blue">Lifestyle</div>
         <div style="float: right; padding: 0 20;">XXXXXX</div>
         <div style="float: right; padding: 0 20;">XXXXXX</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section>
    <div class='post'>
       <div class='post-title>'>TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE</div>
           <div class='tech-title>'>
              <div class='added-by'>MARK NEWCOBE</div>
              <div class='added-at'>10:10:00 12/12/2014</div>
           </div>
           <div class='post-body'>
              <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body</p>
              <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body</p>
              <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body</p>
              <p>Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body Body</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
.blue 
{
  color: blue;
}
.post
{
  width: auto:    
}

.added-by
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.added-at
{
  float: right;      
  font-size: 10px;
}

.post
{
  //position: static;      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all I will suggest you the use of [ClassSelectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) instead of use inline styles.

Then related to your problem is you are using `absolute` position to place the content inside the header section that takes the elements out of the flow and then doesn't take any space making his container `height = 0`. Try with **`float`** instead of `position:absolute` to make them inline:

1. Remove the inline styles for the absolute position and then add this.

   ```
   header > div {
       float:left;
   }
   header:after {
       content:" ";
       display:table;
       clear:both;
   }
   ```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy86p6os/1/)**

Comment: your tip was good :) absolute was the problem:) I did it with float too:) .thanks:) ... Styles were inline because this is still in design:)

Comment: @Pawel glad to help you ... Don't forget to mark your answer as solved, if this was helpfull the chekc icon at the left